# Printing items in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, formatting

I have this list of definitions from a Dictionary API and want to print it out as a string with formatting.

Example of the formatting I am looking for:

```
1. having or marked by great volume or bulk : large; also : full
2. numerous
3. filling or capable of filling a large volume or several volumes
```

This is an example of the list I am working with:

```
['having or marked by great volume or bulk : large; also : full', 'numerous', 'filling or capable of filling a large volume or several volumes']
```

Comment: What do you mean by "print it out with formatting"? Where exactly do you want the result to appear? How are you going to run the program? You cannot have graphical output like this in an ordinary terminal window.

Comment: ok I am using the discord api, I will change my question

Comment: Oh, then you should start with the API documentation. It looks like you're trying to create a Discord *embed*, which should help you with searching the documentation. As far as indicating stuff like boldface and so on, you just do that by supplying the appropriate Markdown text, as if you were using the Discord client yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work, although it won't look as sexy as your picture:

```py
items = ['having or marked by great volume or bulk : large; also : full', 
         'numerous', 
         'filling or capable of filling a large volume or several volumes']

for i in range(len(items)):
    print("{}: {}".format(i+1, items[i]))
```

To do this with `enumerate()` while putting everything into a single string you could do this:

```py
result = []
for i,v in enumerate(items):
    result.append("{}:{}".format(i+1, v))

final = ', '.join(result)
print(final)
```

If you wanted a single string printed but with each element on a different line you could use `join()` like this:

```py
final = '\n'.join(result)
```

Comment: How can I put the correctly formatted text into a single string instead of printed one by one?

Comment: It is more pythonic to use `enumerate`, not `range`.

Comment: Good point @DYZ, I've changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: `enumerate(items,1)` would fit even better.

Comment: Nice! Thanks @DYZ, you made me go back to the documentation. Just learned something. I appreciate it.